# JavaScript constructor function returns parse error while defining properties

Tags: javascript, callback

I created a construction function which will create simple video-game character. The constructor takes `name` as argument and set to property `hName`. The constructed object have other properties, like `speed`, `defaultEnergy`, `energyUsed` and so on (see code). Also, I have two methods inside the constructor function, `description` and `energyLevel`. I want to use `energyLevel` function as callback to `description` function.

The parse error is on line `this.hName: name,`

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var superHero = function (name) {
    this.hName: name,
    speed: 7,
    defaultEnergy: 20,
    energyUsed: 10,
    flyAbility: true,
    description: function (energyLevel) {
        document.write(this.name + " has the capability to hold the hummer.");
        energyLevel();
    },
    energyLevel = function () {
        return ("<br>Current energy level is " + (this.defaultEnergy - this.energyUsed));
    }
};

hero = new superHero("Thor");

document.write(hero.description());
```

I want the following result:

> Thor has the capability to hold the hummer.
>
> Current energy level is 10

I know, it could be achieved very easily without using callback function. But I want to achieve it with callback because I need it in my rest of project, and will also help me to understand why callback is not working.

Comment: Your function almost instantly turns into an object literal. Instead, you want to do something like `function(name){this.hName = name;}` for all of the properties.

Comment: That is not valid javascript. Should be `var hName: name;` or `this.hName = name;`

Comment: yeah, I am trying to construct object with it.

Comment: @MaihanNijat The object construction happens for you; the constructed object is accessed with `this`; as such, put your properties on `this` instead.

Comment: *"will also help me to understand why callback is not working."* - This seems an odd place to be using callback functions: it would make more sense to use this.energyLevel(). But anyway, with your current approach (ignoring all the syntax errors) when you call hero.description() on the last line of your code you don't pass any arguments - so then within that function the energyLevel argument will be undefined. You would have to pass a function as an argument (which in this case isn't really a "callback" since it isn't used to return results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `new Foo`, an object is created *for you* and accessible from within the body of your function. In order to add properties to *that* object, you use the keyword `this`:

```js
function SuperHero ( name ) {
    this.hName = name;
}

var hero = new SuperHero( "Thor" );

console.log( `Name: ${hero.hName}.` );
```

You may also want to put much of this on the function's prototype:

```
function SuperHero ( name ) {
    this.hName = name;
    this.energyLevels = 10;
}

SuperHero.prototype = {
    energyLevel: function () {
        document.write( `Current energy level is ${this.energyLevels}.` );
    },
    description: function ( energyLevel ) {
        document.write( `${this.hName} has a description.` );
        this.energyLevel();
    }
};
```

Items placed on the `SuperHero.prototype` object will be *shared between all instances* of SuperHero.

For further reading, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description.

Comment: It return the name. How can use `hero.description()` to print: `Thor has the capability to hold the hummer.Current energy level is 10`

Comment: @MaihanNijat You probably don't want that description hard-coded into the constructor function/prototype logic. You should instead pass the description into the constructor function, and set it on the object someplace.

Comment: __NOTE:__ This solution uses [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), which are not available in some modern browsers. You may want to rewrite them using normal strings and the `+` operator.

Comment: @usandfriends I believe template string literals are *on* in [all] modern browsers. That being said, thank you for calling it out. Here's an upvote :)

Comment: @Sampson Please check the [browser compat table for template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @usandfriends Internet Explorer is no longer a modern browser; I say this as an engineer on the Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge team ;)

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be changed to this for every single property

```
var superHero = function (name) {
    this.hName = name;

    this.description = function (energyLevel) {
        document.write(this.name + " has the capability to hold the hummer.");
        energyLevel();
    };

};
```

What you're trying to do works for Object creation, but not if you want to create a constructor function.

Comment: You've still got the wrong syntax for this.description.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're trying to assign values doesn't work. Try to rewrite to this:

```
var superHero = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.speed = 7;
    this.defaultEnergy = 20;
    this.energyUsed = 10;
    this.flyAbility = true;   
};

superHero.prototype = {
        description: function (energyLevel) {
        document.write(this.name + " has the capability to hold the hummer.");
        document.write(this.energyLevel());
    },
    energyLevel : function () {
        return ("<br>Current energy level is " + (this.defaultEnergy - this.energyUsed));
    }
}

var hero = new superHero("Thor").description();
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/1zxL48hc/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for answer. It returns `Thor has the capability to hold the hummer.undefined`

Comment: Edited it @MaihanNijat

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a `superHero` class? Use [`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) for class methods and `this.mymember = value;` in the constructor for internal variables. Example:

```js
// class superHero

var superHero = function superHero(name) {
    this.hName = name;
    this.speed = 7;
    this.defaultEnergy = 20;
    this.energyUsed = 10;
    this.flyAbility = true;
};

superHero.prototype.description = function description() {
    document.write(this.hName + " has the capability to hold the hammer.");
    return this.energyLevel();
};

superHero.prototype.energyLevel = function energyLevel() {
    return "<br>Current energy level is " + (this.defaultEnergy - this.energyUsed);
};

// Example

var hero = new superHero("Thor");
document.write(hero.description());
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I vote it up, but couldn't mark it solved as other user replied the fix so early.

Answer (score 1):

This object is completely invalid. You need to choose between a function or an object literal and you're mixing both of these together.

Using an object literal you do this:

```js
var superHero =  {
    name: null,
    speed: 7,
    defaultEnergy: 20,
    energyUsed: 10,
    flyAbility: true,
    description: function (energyLevel) {
        document.write(superHero.name + " has the capability to hold the hummer.");
        superHero.energyLevel();
    },
    energyLevel: function () {
        return ("<br>Current energy level is " + (superHero.defaultEnergy - superHero.energyUsed));
    }
};


//hero = new superHero("Thor");
superHero.name = "Thor";
superHero.description(10);
```

Using a function/class you can do this:

```js
var superHero =  function(name) {
   self = this;
    
    this.name= name;
    this.speed= 7;
    
    defaultEnergy= 20;
    energyUsed = 10;
    flyAbility = true;
    this.description = function (energyLevel) {
   
      document.write(self.name + " has the capability to hold the hummer.");
        self.energyLevel();
    };
    this.energyLevel =  function () {
        return ("<br>Current energy level is " + (selfHero.defaultEnergy - self.energyUsed));
    };
};


hero = new superHero("Thor");
hero.description(10);
```

If it helps you can think of object literals as static object instances and functions as dynamic instances you create more of.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I vote it up, but couldn't mark it solved as other user replied the fix so early.  But your explanation is awesome. It cleared my confusion between the object and function/class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use word 'this' to show what you are working with properties and methods of this current instance of the Constructor function.

```
this.hName = name;
```

and when you call method inside...

```
this.energyLevel();
```